# Attaching a sensor to a link

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to attach a sensor relative to a link so that it moves with the link. I created a link for the sensor but how can I attach this to the other link? I tried pose but this is allowed.

```
 XML Element[pose], child of element[link] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[link]
```

origin pose does work but this is relative to the base.

```
<link name='robot_camera'>
  <pose>0.2 0 0.2 0 0 0</pose>
  <!-- <origin pose="0 0 0 0 -0 0" /> -->
  <!--  <pose="1 1 0 0 0 0"/> -->
  <!--<origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/> -->
  <inertial mass="0.1">
    <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1" iyz="0" izz="1"/>
  </inertial>

  <visual name="visual">
    <origin pose="0 0 0 0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
    </geometry>
  </visual>

  <sensor name='camera' type='camera' always_on='1' update_rate='30' visualize='true'>
    <camera>
      <horizontal_fov angle='1.57079633'/>
        <image width='640' height='480' format='R8G8B8'/>
        <clip near='0.1' far='100'/>
    </camera>
    <plugin name="camera_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
      <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
      <updateRate>30.0</updateRate>
      <cameraName>arm_camera</cameraName>
      <frameName>/openni_camera</frameName>
      <CxPrime>320.5</CxPrime>
      <Cx>320.5</Cx>
      <Cy>240.5</Cy>
      <hackBaseline>0</hackBaseline>
      <focalLength>320.000101</focalLength>
      <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
      <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
      <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
      <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
      <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
    </plugin>
  </sensor>
</link>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1127/attaching-a-sensor-to-a-link/) by [Davinci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/108/davinci/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 65 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The xml you have posted is based on the format used in Gazebo < 1.0. It should look something like:

```
<link name='robot_camera'>
  <pose>0.2 0 0.2 0 0 0</pose>

  <visual name="visual">
    <geometry>
      <box>
        <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
      </box>
    </geometry>
  </visual>

  <sensor name='camera' type='camera'>
    <always_on>true</always_on>
    <update_rate>30</update_rate>

    <camera>
      <horizontal_fov>1.5707</horizontal_fov>
      <image>
        <width>640</width>
        <height>480</height>
      </image>
      <clip>
        <near>0.1</near>
        <far>100</far>
      </clip>
    </camera>

    <plugin name="camera_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
      <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
      <updateRate>30.0</updateRate>
      <cameraName>arm_camera</cameraName>
      <frameName>/openni_camera</frameName>
      <CxPrime>320.5</CxPrime>
      <Cx>320.5</Cx>
      <Cy>240.5</Cy>
      <hackBaseline>0</hackBaseline>
      <focalLength>320.000101</focalLength>
      <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
      <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
      <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
      <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
      <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
    </plugin>
  </sensor>
</link>
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0